# CSS code after an animation doesn't work

Tags: css, image, animation

I have a question a bout why my CSS code doesn't work when put after an animation.

Here is the example :

```
img {
    max-width: 50px;
}

@keyframes slidedown {
  from {
    margin-top: 100%;
    height: 300%;

  to {
    margin-top: 0%;
    height: 300%;
  }
}

img {
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

img will be 50px if I put it before the animation, and will fill the entire page when put after the animation.

This is just an example (the animation is about a text). But I can't understand why my CSS code doesn't work written after the animation.

Comment: show us that it's not working so we can see ... it's probably something else

Comment: `Problem solved, a bracket lacked at the end of the animation.` --> better deleted the question then before you get downvotes and close votes

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: It's best to run your code through and editor/tester like JS Fiddle before posting to Stack Overflow. A simple copy/paste shows your error.

Comment: But I can't delete it since there were answers, sorry for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `}` after the `from` declaration and before the `to` declaration. Try:

```
@keyframes slidedown {
  from {
    margin-top: 100%;
    height: 300%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0%;
    height: 300%;
  }
}
```